# Rolling back bulk inserts with spark SQL Server connector

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark to write to an SQL Server.

I am using the following approach (pseudo-code):

- Using pyodbc I issue a drop table if exists and a CREATE TABLE statement specifying column names, data types and nullability. One could also think of scenarios where one wants to create a clustered columnstore index and a unique constraint instead of a primary key.
- Using pyspark and the ms spark jdbc connector with overwrite and truncate options I insert the rows of my df into this HEAP. I turn of strict schema checks bc columns of the spark df are nullable
- When writing to a Heap instead of CCI, I issue an ALTER TABLE statement to set a primary key contraint

Now, when the bulk insert of spark.write fails, e.g. because of a violation of the nullability, all rows up to that error get inserted. The write call raises a python/scala error.

**Note that the same happens with mode "append"** when inserting into an existing table.

How can i tweak the write methods and options to roll back all inserts upon error in a row.

spark write call:

```
df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", sqldbuser) \
        .option("password", sqldbpwd) \
        .option("schemaCheckEnabled", False) \
        .option("BatchSize", 1048576) \
        .option("truncate", True) \
        .save()
```

Comment: Are you certain it's actually running `BULK INSERT` and not a series of "normal" `INSERT` statements?

Comment: from my understanding it bulk inserts under the hood https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Try setting the `reliabilityLevel` to NO_DUPLICATES? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-options

Comment: Although i was sceptical at first, this seems to work. However, the error message is now much more neboulous: java.sql.SQLException: Failed dues to non-transient error. No records written. Irrespective of failure due to data type/nullability/any other error

Comment: Maybe use a transaction?

Comment: I tried using: .option("UseInternalTransaction", True) to no effect. I am basically looking for the safest way possible to do writes and appends. Setting the reliability level to no duplicates works but makes the error message unusable. Right now I am just writing to a temporary staging table to be extra safe and then either copy the table or insert if i want to do appends.